# IDEA, importing projects to new version of an IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

I am moving code along from IntelliJ 11C to 12Ultimate.

I ended up creating a new Project at a new location (intentionally) i like and now would like to import all existing modules to it.

Now .. when i do it, at some point, it attempts to modify an existing xml configuration file, which if possible i'd like to avoid.

Make simple, i want to move all modules from CE11 to 12 using CE11's configuration under a new project in 12.

Is imports the right thing to do? Should i create new ones?

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your team is using different IntelliJ IDEA versions, it's recommended to have 2 copies of project/module files as the format may be not backwards compatible (new options added to the configuration by IDEA 12 will be stripped down from XMLs by older versions).

Normally you just open IDEA 11 project in IDEA 12 and it's converted automatically. If there were any major changes to the format, backup of the project/module files is created automatically.

Importing individual modules will also work, but just opening projects is the recommended way.